# Parameter Syntax Error using VB and DataRow Select Statement

Tags: vb.net, parameters, datarow

Can someone tell me why is I hard code the Parameter Value, this line works

```
Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select("GroupID = 'TDAX015A'")
```

But if I try to use the actual Parameter I'm passing, this line does not work?

```
Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select("GroupID = @cGID")
```

I get the error:

> can't find Column.

---

Here's the whole function:

```
Private Function GetGroup(ByVal cGID As String) As Boolean

    Dim lValidGroup = False

    Dim dtGroupMaster As DataTable = NewBenefitsDataSet.GroupMaster

    'Test valid group
    cGID = "TDAX015A"

    ' Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select("GroupID = @cGID")  - doesn't work

    'Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select("GroupID = " + cGID) - doesn't work

    Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select("GroupID = 'TDAX015A'")  - works fine

    For Each row As DataRow In result
        lValidGroup = True
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(lValidGroup)

    Return lValidGroup
End Function
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I added that line 'Test Valid Group to try to force the function - put if I passed it from the calling program, I get the same result.

Comment: The syntax for the [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) does not appear to have any provision for using parameters.

Comment: You probably meant to write `Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select($"GroupID = '{cGID}'")`. The `$` does "string interpolation", and it needs single-quotes around the value. If you're using an earlier VS, then `Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select("GroupID = '" & cGID &"'")`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I got it to work using this Syntax

Dim result() As DataRow = dtGroupMaster.Select("GroupID = '" + cGID + "'")

Comment: Do note that the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`. You can get undesired results with the latter.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I made the change and it worked perfectly...appreciate that.

Comment: @JeffreyClarke You can accept your own answer. It won't give you reps but it will mark the question as answered.